# How to create a Class that can be a representative of a recurring excel table

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

I have tables in Excel that look like this:

```
dimension|all |group1|group2
dim1     |0.23|0.65  |0.89  
dim2     |0.08|0.87  |0.21  
dim3     |0.47|0.21  |0.68  

Employees|sum |n |freq  
dim1     |0.38|22|0.11 
dim2     |0.98|65|0.47  
dim3     |0.98|78|0.58
```

As you can see the Table Structure keeps the same as well as the row names. Only thing that changes is the column names and the datatype even though the type is always either int or decimal.

I am looking for a way to build an object that can store the data. My approach was something like this.

```
Public MustInherit Class Categories_POCO
    Public Property dim1 As Array
    Public Property dim2 As Array
    Public Property dim3 As Array
    Public Property dim4 As Array
End Class

Public Class Dimension
    Inherits Categories_POCO
    Public Property all_MA As Dictionary(
End Class
```

But I stuck here a bit and do not know how to go on further. Anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: Why not make use of Objects? I mean instead of Integer or Double, just use Object

Comment: I suggest making a different Class for each thing. Then you could have an overall Class with those classes in, if that was appropriate.

Comment: *"Only thing that changes is the column names and the datatype"*. Yeah, those are fairly important things. A property IS it's name and data type.  You need different classes.  Anything else is just bad design.

Comment: You mean one class for e.g. dimension, one for employee and so on and that I should not work with inheritance?

Comment: Inheritance is not just about working with data. What exactly is a "dimension" and is there some thing that both a dimension and an Employee are specialised types of?  If not, there's not really a good reason to be considering inheritance at all.

Comment: I thought since both have dim1-dim3 and the same structure I can create a parent class  for this.

Comment: You can do what you want but there should be a reason for it. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Inheritance exists for a reason. It's supposed to represent an actual relationship between types. What's the relationship logical here?

Comment: You could create a generic structure (using a Class module) that identifies the number of columns, the number of rows, the headings for each column, the "dim" for each row - with flexibility for any number of rows and columns, and (of course) the array of data in any type that is required. Surprisingly, that is relatively easy (the Class will *look* complex in the end). However, why do this when Excel has already done that work for you? Perhaps the `ListObject` is the first thing to look at?